# change the margin on each slideToggle() call by x%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to reduce my containers magin step by step when using `slideToggle()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    doIt();
  });
});

function doIt() {
  var container = $("#c2");
  var maxMarginTop = container.css("marginTop").replace('px', '');
  var maxMarginBottom = container.css("marginBottom").replace('px', '');

  container.slideToggle({
    duration: 2000,
    progress: function(animation, progress, remainingMilliseconds) {
      var newMarginTop = maxMarginTop - (maxMarginTop * progress);
      var newMarginBottom = maxMarginBottom - (maxMarginBottom * progress);

      container.css("margin-top", newMarginTop);
      container.css("margin-bottom", newMarginBottom);
    },
    complete: function() {
      container.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Do it</button>

<div class="container" id="c1">
</div>

<div class="container" id="c2">
</div>

<div class="container" id="c3">
</div>
```

I have to execute code on each step within the slide function. I calculate the new margin based on the current progress.

So the margin should go from 100% to 0% represented by the progress.

Within the progress function I calculate the new margin and when logging the new values this works fine.

But as you can see nothing happens. When logging the margin value in the complete function nothing changed.

Is it a wrong scope? What is happening there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have added both top and bottom margin which causes a [collapsing margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) - ie you only get 20px of margin.  Therefore, you may as well start off with one margin and then it will animate properly

Why not do this with css animation:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#c2").addClass('closed');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  /* do not need the bottom margin due to collapsing margins */
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.container.closed {
  height:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Do it</button>

<div class="container" id="c1">
</div>

<div class="container" id="c2">
</div>

<div class="container" id="c3">
</div>
```

If you want to carry on using js animations, just remove one of your margins:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    doIt();
  });
});

function doIt() {
  var container = $("#c2");
  var maxMarginTop = container.css("marginTop").replace('px', '');
  var maxMarginBottom = container.css("marginBottom").replace('px', '');

  container.slideToggle({
    duration: 2000,
    progress: function(animation, progress, remainingMilliseconds) {
      var newMarginTop = maxMarginTop - (maxMarginTop * progress);
      var newMarginBottom = maxMarginBottom - (maxMarginBottom * progress);

      container.css("margin-top", newMarginTop);
    },
    complete: function() {
      container.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Do it</button>

<div class="container" id="c1">
</div>

<div class="container" id="c2">
</div>

<div class="container" id="c3">
</div>
```